# How to mount additional Windows partitions in a WUBI installed Ubuntu?

Tags: wubi, mount

I am new to Ubuntu. I was using Windows Vista Ultimate before I came to Ubuntu.

Can you give me a solution to discover all my files? I have two partition in Windows: `C:` and `D:\`.

In `D:\`, I kept all my files, movies, songs, pictures, books, games, backups & etc. But I cannot find any of these in Ubuntu. In fact I can't even find my `D:\`. All I found is a folder name "Host" and there I can see all my `C:\` files.

Please help me. All of my important files are in `D:\`.

- I downloaded Ubuntu 12.04 and installed it with WUBI. Is this the cause for not seeing my folders? Should I install Ubuntu from a CD or USB?
- I can't even connect to Internet. I am using a Broadband connection. What should I do?

Please help me and make me a user of Ubuntu. Otherwise, I have to go back to Microsoft Windows Vista/7.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell Ubuntu to mount your additional partition.

Press the Win-key and type "disk". You should see the icon called "disk utility". You will be able to browse all your disks and partition. Once you have located what is known to windows as `D:` (`D:` is a Windows-specific label), you will be able to mount it such that you can browse all your files stored there.

An explanation to "mounting": Windows automatically mounts the physical partitions such that you can find them at mount points labeled `C:`, `D:` etc. In Linux / Unix, you can choose the mount point freely (it can be any empty folder). For example, your partition that is mounted as `C:` in Windows has been mounted at the mount point `/host`.